# How do I get a button and a count box inline the full width of the container no matter the width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button and a container on a single line and I'm trying to get the button to be the full width (`btn-block` in bootstrap) while the count box is on the same line. The problem right now is I can get the button on the same line, if I give it a fixed width, but that doesn't work if the container is a smaller width on other resolutions or if the button has a count of `4834` instead of `3` for example.

Here is what I have now:

```
<div class="button-container">

 <div class="btn btn-primary">Boo</div>
 <div id="count_box" class="count_box">42</div>

</div>
```

The `.count_box` has this CSS:

```
.count_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    top: 1px;
    color: #333;
}
```

Note that `.button_container` can be 600px wide or 200px wide, etc. So I can't give it a fixed width. A jsFiddle explains it better than the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/gdrpmr13/1/

Is there any easy way to do get both the button and the count on the same line and the button being 100% (minus the width of the count)? I'm lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with some smart float manipulations, so that all widths are dynamic and still button fills remaining width. Note, that I added class `pull-right` to count box and moved it *before* button.

```css
.button-container .btn {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.count_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    top: 1px;
    color: #333;
}
.count_box:after, .count_box:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: medium solid transparent;
    content:" ";
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.count_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) #FFF rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.count_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0) #333 rgba(221, 221, 221, 0) rgba(221, 221, 221, 0);
    border-width: 9px;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
.button-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    padding:20px 0px;
}
.button-container-2 {
    margin-top:20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    padding:20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="button-container">
    <div class="count_box pull-right">42</div>
    <div class="btn btn-primary">Boo</div>
</div>
<div class="button-container">
    <div class="count_box pull-right">4333234</div>
    <div class="btn btn-primary">Boo</div>
</div>
```

And here is another demo with demonstrates how it would work when parent container is resized (resize demo pane): http://jsfiddle.net/gdrpmr13/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can make the count part of let's say `60px` and button of remaining width.

So you should choose this **60px width** by assuming the maximum count you're expecting in there and then align it the way you want.

**HTML**

```
<div class="button-container">

<div class="btn btn-primary btn-block-almost">Boo</div>
<div id="count_box" class="count_box">42</div>

</div>

<div class="button-container-2">

<div class="btn btn-primary btn-block-almost">Boo</div>
<div id="count_box" class="count_box">4255</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.count_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    top: 1px;
    color: #333;
    width: 60px;
}
.btn-block-almost{
 width: calc(100% - 80px);   
}
```

Just added some css and a class to your markup and this looks fine to me

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arpit_goyal/81npkrdj/

Comment: I don't see how that works if the container width varies and the count_box also varies (if there's a 2 or a 434)?

Comment: Thanks for your updated version. I'll try that right now!

Comment: you said you can not give fixed width as it makes them staack over each other, in this case it won't happen.